# Why does my WM make the x-terminal-emulator black?

Tags: c, terminal, window-managers

I am new to C programming. I started writing a very basic window manager for X. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/MaximilianAlgehed/WM).

It does what it's supposed to do just fine (more functionality inbound) when I use `dmenu` to start programs it works like a charm. However, there is one program that simply won't comply, `x-terminal-emulator`. It's simply just black. I can type input and it executes commands (e.g. exit), but I can't see the text in the terminal. Any thoughs?

EDIT: The terminal that won't display text (to be more specific) is lxterminal, xterm still starts for an instance.

Note: I'm still at university so please excuse my basic knowledge.

Comment: It could be starting, but just miscolored due to its own preferences.  Is this consistent with the way it behaves with another window manager?

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I checked that. In the configuration it said white on  black, and in dwm it behaves just as expected (i.e. visible output). And yes, it is starting (hence why exit works to close it) but it is not displaying the information.